# Permission denied when changing hosts file on M1 mac

Tags: bash, hosts

The error is

```
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/etc/hosts'
```

Got the program to work on my own mac, but it doesn't work on my girlfriend's machine.

The problem lies with this part when executing a bash script `blocker.sh` containing this:

```
sudo mv /tmp/etc_hosts.tmp /etc/hosts
```

I have edited both our sudoers file to contain

```
$username  ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /Users/$username/blocker.sh
```

Editing the sudoers file should make it  permissionless to execute `blocker.sh` right?

Both machines are running Big Sur, but her machine is a 2020 M1 mac.

Comment: What macOS is on each Mac?

Comment: @Tetsujin both are Big Sur's, but hers is an M1 2020

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. The line `$username  ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /Users/$username/blocker.sh` let's you run `sudo /Users/$username/blocker.sh` without entering a password. Do you run `blocker.sh` with `sudo`, that is, is this the command you use `sudo /Users/$username/blocker.sh`?

Comment: @jaume Yup! That's the case. More specifically, `sudo ~/blocker.sh`

Comment: Thanks, have you tried running the `mv` command without `sudo`, that is, removing `sudo` from `sudo mv`?